# Part of my click function doesn't work until second click

Tags: jquery, load, click

I'm trying to generate some content when the user clicks on a particular link. This generated content serves as a loading div for some ajax content. Everything works, except for the loading div is not created until I click the link a second time.  What's causing this?

Here is the live page: http://tickets.ebridgesites.com/tickets.php

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<table id="list">
...
    <tr id="ticketID-1">
        <td><a href="ticket-details.php" class="alert" title="Alert">A descriptive ticket title</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="more" data-more-type="client">Business World Inc</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="more" data-more-type="contact">Fran Bumpkins</a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="more" data-more-type="employee">John Miller</a>
            <!-- ajax-parts/more-employees.php goes here -->
        </td>
        <td>Jan 25, 20:35</td>
        <td>On-site</td>
        <td>Open</td>
        <td class="listAddTime"><a href="#">5.25</a></td>
    </tr> 
....
```

And here is the jQuery being used:

```
$('#list a.more').live('click', function() {
var type = $(this).attr('data-more-type');
var ticket = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

// place the relative positioned div as a container for .moreOptions box
var relativeDiv = '<div class="relative"></div>';
$(this).after(relativeDiv);
alert('div.relative should be inserted here but does not until second click');

$('#'+ticket+' .relative').load('inc/ajax-parts/more-'+type+'.php');

return false;// prevent default of a.more link
});
```

Comment: Could I suggest amending `var ticket = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');` to `var ticket = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');`, to make it a little more flexible if the structure changes?

Comment: BTW, when the ajax content is loaded in, you won't see it because it's styled to be hidden.  But you can see it loaded in on the second click with Firebug.

Comment: @ David Thomas - yes, that sounds great.  I've never used .closest() before

Comment: @Ben, how about styling it *not* to be hidden so that we can see it..? =)

Comment: @David Thomas - Done!  now shows.

Comment: Just as a heads-up, it works first time in Chrome 8, IE 8 and Firefox 3.6.x (Win XP). What browser/platform is causing the problem?

Comment: @David - See my answer, if you post something the same I'll check it as the answered question.

Comment: @ben: I appreciate the thought, but it's okay; I only made a suggestion that showing the `div` would be helpful. You found that it was being added properly ahead of me. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following David's advice to show the div, I now see that it may be a Firebug issue, and not an issue with my code.  I made the ajaxed content visible and see that it actually shows up immediately, but doesn't show up in firebug.